# Read Xcode Build Settings from terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal

I found you can get a list of all environment variables from my project`s build settings by doing:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project <project>.xcodeproj
```

It also prints out the PROVISIONING_PROFILE, which I want to use for a build script

```
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = d0eff791-6b39-4d9b-a164-3e768f63b333
```

however if I do a

```
echo $PROVISIONING_PROFILE
```

or

```
sudo echo $PROVISIONING_PROFILE
```

it prints nothing.

How can I access the `${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}` variable from outside XCode, like in terminal or a build script?

Comment: This is hugely helpful as I wanted to align two targets - dumped both (added a "-target <name>" to the command), then used Xcode's "File Merge" app to diff them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution...

```
export PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$(xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project <project>.xcodeproj | grep PROVISIONING_PROFILE | cut -d' ' -c3)
```

Comment: I see, I actually think the solution is not bad, but why the cut -d' ' -c3 ?

Comment: To get the 3rd element of `PROVISIONING_PROFILE = d0eff791-6b39-4d9b-a164-3e768f63b333`.

Comment: I needed to use `cut -f 7 -d ' '` with the cut tool on High Sierra with output of Xcode 9.2. It was also useful to `grep " ${var_name} "` (i.e. search with spaces around name) to eliminate partial matches of other variable names.

Comment: you could use the pcregrep instead and just show the output match at 1: `export PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$(xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project <project>.xcodeproj | pcregrep -o1 "PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ([0-9a-f\-]+)")`